# OpenGL code to display simple text in different size?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I used the following code to display some simple text:

```
    void output(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, char *format,...)
{
  va_list args;
  char buffer[200], *p;

  va_start(args, format);
  vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
  va_end(args);
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(x, y, -1000);
  for (p = buffer; *p; p++)
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *p);
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

But I don't know how could I change/specify the size of the text?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please [never use vsprintf](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm). And I don't mean to start using iostream or something; I mean to use vs**n**printf. That way, you don't walk off the end of your character array.

Second, you should be using `glutStrokeString` to draw a string.

Most importantly, since the GLUT text rendering code uses the current matrix, if you want to change the size of the text, you can just drop a scale matrix into the matrix stack with `glScalef`. This probably only works with stroked fonts though, which you are using.